# Submitting 'aspnetForm' using Ruby Mechanize is not working as expected

Tags: ruby, webforms, mechanize, scrape

I am using ruby mechanize gem to automate form submission and scrape the results. I have the following code:

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'logger'

url = "http://www.cebupacificair.com/Pages/default.aspx"
agent = Mechanize.new do |agent| 
  agent.log = Logger.new(STDOUT)
  agent.follow_meta_refresh = true 
end
page = agent.get(url)

search_results = page.form_with(:name => 'aspnetForm') do |form|
  form['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = ''
  form['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$LinkButtonNewSearch'
  form.radiobutton_with(:value => "RoundTrip").check
  form.field_with(:name => "ddOrigin").options_with(:value => "MNL").select
  form.field_with(:name => "ddDestination").options_with(:value => "SGN").select
  form.field_with(:name => "_depmonthyear").options_with(:value => "2013-02").select
  form.field_with(:name => "_depday").options_with(:value => "9").select
  form.field_with(:name => "_retmonthyear").options_with(:value => "2013-02").select
  form.field_with(:name => "_retday").options_with(:value => "11").select
  form.field_with(:name => "_adults").options_with(:value => "1").select
  form.field_with(:name => "_children").options_with(:value => "0").select
  form.field_with(:name => "_infants").options_with(:value => "0").select
end.click_button

puts search_results.body
```

when I run the code above, it submits the form but it doesn't redirect to a page where I was redirected when I do the submit manually. Here's the log:

```
Starting run ...
I, [2012-08-27T08:37:08.010661 #4] INFO -- : Net::HTTP::Get: /Pages/default.aspx
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:08.010794 #4] DEBUG -- : request-header: accept => */*
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:08.010825 #4] DEBUG -- : request-header: user-agent => Mechanize/2.3 Ruby/1.9.2...more
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:08.010849 #4] DEBUG -- : request-header: accept-encoding => gzip,deflate,identity
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:08.010873 #4] DEBUG -- : request-header: accept-charset => ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:08.010898 #4] DEBUG -- : request-header: accept-language => en-us,en;q=0.5
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:08.010922 #4] DEBUG -- : request-header: host => www.cebupacificair.com
I, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.354481 #4] INFO -- : status: Net::HTTPOK 1.1 200 OK
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.354778 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: cache-control => private, max-age=0
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.354869 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: content-type => text/html; charset=utf-8
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.354945 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: content-encoding => gzip
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.355017 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: expires => Sun, 12 Aug 2012 08:37:09 GMT
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.355089 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: last-modified => Mon, 27 Aug 2012 08:37:09 GMT
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.355161 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: vary => Accept-Encoding
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.355232 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: server => Microsoft-IIS/7.0
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.355313 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: x-aspnet-version => 2.0.50727
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.355386 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: x-powered-by => ASP.NET
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.355457 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: microsoftsharepointteamservices => 12.0.0.6420
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.355528 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: date => Mon, 27 Aug 2012 08:37:09 GMT
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.355599 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: content-length => 19031
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.355668 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: connection => close
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.355739 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: set-cookie => MyCookie=8npRAWS5i10kju...more
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.356068 #4] DEBUG -- : Read 6698 bytes (6698 total)
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.356328 #4] DEBUG -- : Read 12333 bytes (19031 total)
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.356890 #4] DEBUG -- : gzip response
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.375285 #4] DEBUG -- : saved cookie: MyCookie=8npRAWS5i10kjuDl8xX/01gRq0obDLa...more
I, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.385797 #4] INFO -- : form encoding: utf-8
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.388509 #4] DEBUG -- : query: "MSOWebPartPage_PostbackSource=&MSOTlPn_Selecte...more
I, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.390797 #4] INFO -- : Net::HTTP::Post: /Pages/default.aspx
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.390897 #4] DEBUG -- : request-header: accept => */*
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.390927 #4] DEBUG -- : request-header: user-agent => Mechanize/2.3 Ruby/1.9.2...more
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.390966 #4] DEBUG -- : request-header: accept-encoding => gzip,deflate,identity
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.390991 #4] DEBUG -- : request-header: accept-charset => ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.391015 #4] DEBUG -- : request-header: accept-language => en-us,en;q=0.5
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.391039 #4] DEBUG -- : request-header: cookie => MyCookie=8npRAWS5i10kjuDl8xX...more
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.391063 #4] DEBUG -- : request-header: host => www.cebupacificair.com
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.391095 #4] DEBUG -- : request-header: referer => http://www.cebupacificair.c...more
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.391123 #4] DEBUG -- : request-header: content-type => application/x-www-form...more
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.391146 #4] DEBUG -- : request-header: content-length => 13733
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:11.391170 #4] DEBUG -- : request-header: if-modified-since => Mon, 27 Aug 2012 ...more
I, [2012-08-27T08:37:19.039011 #4] INFO -- : status: Net::HTTPOK 1.1 200 OK
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:19.039252 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: cache-control => private
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:19.039348 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: content-type => text/html; charset=utf-8
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:19.039428 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: content-encoding => gzip
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:19.039501 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: vary => Accept-Encoding
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:19.039580 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: server => Microsoft-IIS/7.0
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:19.039652 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: x-aspnet-version => 2.0.50727
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:19.039725 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: x-powered-by => ASP.NET
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:19.039798 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: microsoftsharepointteamservices => 12.0.0.6420
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:19.039895 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: date => Mon, 27 Aug 2012 08:37:17 GMT
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:19.040003 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: content-length => 20962
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:19.040074 #4] DEBUG -- : response-header: connection => close
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:19.040338 #4] DEBUG -- : Read 6906 bytes (6906 total)
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:19.040605 #4] DEBUG -- : Read 14056 bytes (20962 total)
D, [2012-08-27T08:37:19.041137 #4] DEBUG -- : gzip response
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> <html __...more
Finished: 12.393 seconds elapsed
runfinished
```

Anyone knows what am I missing here? Do I need a different settings for mechanize to work on asp forms?

Thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: To me, it looks like the form is not being submitted at all (ie the search_result.body is still the initial page). The problem might be that the search button has an onclick event. Unfortunately Mechanize does not handle javascript, so you would need to either figure out what the onclick event is doing and replicate it or use a gem that supports javascript like Watir or Watir-Webdriver.

Comment: Thanks @justin. The button does have a js onlick event. Will look into the page source to see what the event does. I'll post an update after...

Answer (score 2):

Try a different approach.

If it's a post request that it makes. Try making that request manually instead of using Mechanizes form handler:

The params it submits are:

```
__EVENTTARGET=ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24LinkButtonNewSearch
__EVENTARGUMENT=
__VIEWSTATE=
ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24RadioButtonMarketStructure=RoundTrip
ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24TextBoxMarketOrigin1=BWN
ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24TextBoxMarketDestination1=PEK
ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24DropDownListMarketDay1=11
ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24DropDownListMarketMonth1=2013-06
ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24DropDownListMarketDay2=11
ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24DropDownListMarketMonth2=2013-06
ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24DropDownListPassengerType_ADT=1
ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24DropDownListPassengerType_CHD=0
ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24DropDownListPassengerType_INFANT=0
ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24promoCodeID=
```

So what you could do is to:

```
# 1. Get the frontpage to get the cookie set:
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get(url)
# 2. The use .search helper to extract the inputs you might need
# 3. Submit the form by sending the postparams manually
result_page = agent.post("http://book.cebupacificair.com/Search.aspx?culture=en-us", {'__EVENTTARGET' => 'ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24LinkButtonNewSearch'}) # And of cause add the remaining params...
```

I'm sure this approach will work for you...

Comment: Thanks Niels. This worked for me. Mechanize does not handle javaxcript so javascript links etc need to be handled the way you described.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Helped me understand what format the POST params should be in. Note, `{ __EVENTTARGET: "something"}` isn't what the web server is looking for!